# How do I download documents from AtTask?

Tags: c#, api, attask

I'm working on a continuing API project. The current issue at hand is to be able to download my data from the AtTask server in precisely the folder structure they exist in on the AtTask servers. I've got the folder creation working nicely; the data types between Document, Document Folder and Document Version seem to be pretty clear. I am a little disillusioned about the fact that extension isn't in the document object (that I have to refer to the document VERSION for that)... but I can see some of the reason for that from a design perspective.

The issue I'm running into now is that I need to get the file content. I originally through from the API documentation that I'd be able to get to the file contents the same way as the documentation recommends uploading it -- through the handle. Unfortunately, neither document nor docv seem to support me accessing the handle except to write a new file.

So that leaves me the "download URL" as the remaining option. If I build the UI strings from the API calls using my browser, I get a URL with `https://attaskURL/document/download?ID=xxxx` (and can also get the versionID and such). If I paste the url into the browser where I'm logged in to the user interface of AtTask, it works fine and I can download the file. If, instead, I use my C# code to do so, I get the login page returned as a stream for me to download instead of my actual file because I'm not authenicated. I've tried creating a network credential and attaching it to the request with the username and password, but to no avail.

I imagine there's a couple ways to solve this problem -- the easy one being finding a way to "log in" to the download site through code (which doesn't seem to be the usual network credential object in C#) OR find a way to access the file contents through the API.

Appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can use the download URL if you put a session id in the URL. The details on getting a session id are here (basically just call login and a session id is returned in JSON):

http://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#Authentication

Then cram it on the end of your document download URL:

https://yourcompany.attask-ondemand.com/document/download?ID=xxxx&sessionID=abc1234

I've given this a quick test and I'm able to access a document.

Comment: That was the trick. The download URL was redirecting me to the login page when I didn't tag it with an existing session. I assumed it was a different login management system since the response codes were different through Fiddler, but you're absolutely right and saved me a ton of unnecessary login calls. :)

Comment: I tried using  sessionID but not  working in my case. Still redirecting to the login page. Any idea what might be the issue here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the downloadURL and a sessionID IF you are not using SAML authentication.

I have tried it both ways and using SAML will redirect you to the login page.